# New symbol derived from [a, b]

Tags: draw

I would like to draw the following new symbol, so that I can use it in sentences.

[image]

Which tool would you advise? TikZ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just need normal text inside?

Comment: Yes, I just need symbols such as $P$, $Q$, $z$, $a$. Thanks.

Comment: So it seems more like math, not text.

Comment: I want to use this symbol in math mode, such as in $[a,b] = \{ ta + (1-t)b ; t\in [0,1] \}$.

Comment: Is there a name for this symbol or a reference to where is used?

Comment: My students invented it this morning... 

Comment: My professor used `[\![a,b]\!]` instead.

Comment: But this usually denotes the interval of integers between $a$ and $b$...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Was your professor's use also for [integer intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Integer_intervals)?  Do you know of a reference where this symbol is used?

Comment: @PeterGrill Definitly not for integer intevals -- I've met that notation in lecture of differential geometry ...  He introduced it to  describe the line segment between two points of a vector space.  Unfortunately I can't give a reference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Before someone comes with a Ti*k*Z solution `:-)`...

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{{\mathpalette\foo@{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\foo@}[2]{%
   \@tempdima=.5\fontdimen5
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi\tw@
   \@tempdimb=\fontdimen8
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi\thr@@
   \setbox\z@=\vtop{\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}\kern\@tempdima}%
   \setbox\tw@=\vbox{\hrule\@width\@tempdima\@height\@tempdimb\kern\ht\z@\kern\@tempdima}%
   \vtop{\hbox{\vrule\@width\@tempdimb\copy\tw@\copy\z@\copy\tw@\vrule\@width\@tempdimb}\hrule\@height\@tempdimb}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\foo{a,b}$
$\scriptstyle\foo{a,b}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\foo{a,b}$

\medskip
$\displaystyle\foo{-\frac{a}{2},\frac{a}{2}}$
$\foo{-\frac{a}{2},\frac{a}{2}}$
$\scriptstyle\foo{-\frac{a}{2},\frac{a}{2}}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\foo{-\frac{a}{2},\frac{a}{2}}$

\end{document}
```

The two lengths scale according to the current math style: `\@tempdimb` is the fraction rule thickness, while `\@tempdima` is half `ex` (the latter could be fixed without resorting to `\fontdimen`).

[image]

If you uncomment `amsmath` then the result will differ slightly in `\scriptscriptstyle`, where you get

without `amsmath`:
[image]

with `amsmath`:
[image]

With the shorter code

```
\newcommand*{\foo@}[2]{%
   \@tempdima=.5\fontdimen5
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi\tw@
   \setbox\z@=\vtop{\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}\kern\@tempdima}%
   \setbox\tw@=\vbox{\hrule\@width\@tempdima\kern\ht\z@\kern\@tempdima}%
   \vtop{\hbox{\vrule\copy\tw@\copy\z@\copy\tw@\vrule\@width\@tempdimb}\hrule}%
}
```

the "box" has the default thickness of `0.4pt` in every style.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you 

Answer (score 9):

If your symbols don't have excessive depth (no fractions, for instance), you can get away with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\segment}[1]{%
  \big\lceil\colas@segment{#1}\big\rceil
}
\newcommand{\colas@segment}[1]{%
  \mspace{-4.85mu}%
  \underline{\mspace{5mu}#1\vphantom{j}\mspace{5mu}}%
  \mspace{-4.85mu}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Huge

\indent\rlap{\vrule height0pt depth0.1pt width 4cm}%
$\segment{a,b}=\{ta+(1-t)b: t\in[0,1]\}$

\indent\rlap{\vrule height0pt depth0.1pt width 4cm}%
$\segment{p,q}=\{tp+(1-t)q: t\in[0,1]\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!